# Spring security welcome page accessible even after logout

Tags: spring, spring-security, logout

I am new to spring security. I was following this tutorial

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

everything works fine when we request for welcome page it redirects to login form and then after entering the credentials gives welcome page.The problem is when i click logout it does logout but welcome page is still accessible  we i hit ...@localhost/SpringSecurity2/welcome and it does not ask for login.I guess its related to session but not getting how to solve this.I also used  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" but  it is not working.

I just want when user logsout and again hit welcome url.he should be directed to login form not welcome page as it requires authentication. need help soon
 my security xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout 
        logout-success-url="/logout" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" /> add this to your logout tag and also you should implement logoutSuccessHandler in your application.

Comment: i have done that but thats not working ..it gives 404 error that its unable to found logout. can u please tell how to implement logoutsuccesshandler.

Comment: check your loginController and in that what you have returned for logout method. I am talking about mapping page.

Comment: It sounds as though it is a cache issue. If you use Spring Security 3.2 this can be solved using the new headers support. See http://blog.springsource.org/2013/08/23/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-security-headers/#cache-control

Comment: I've downloaded source codes from http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/ and build up it to `war`. Then I deploy into `tomcat` and it works fine. I suggest that you do the same and compare files to find out what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write `SessionFilter` class by implementing `javax.servlet.Filter` class as follows.

```
package com.filter;
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(null == session){
            response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and also mention it in your **web.xml** file as follows

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.SessionFilter   
</filter-class>
```

and dont forget to ***invalidate your session*** in logout controller using follows statement

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: so we have to create our own filter for this...Spring Security does not have any built in Functionality to kill that particular user session?

Comment: Spring Security by default kills the session. My guess is that you are looking at a local copy (cached version) of your welcome page. Try the following, goto the page and refresh (or CTRL refresh), probably you will then be asked for a username/password.

Comment: @palak spring will kill the session after the time period you have mentioned in session timeout attribute but in your case you have to kill the user session on logout event thus you have to write code to invalidate session when user logout.